# How to get specific terms from a python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list A.

```
 A = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
```

I want to search the character 7 and if found,i would like the character before and after it get back as result.

```
desired result = ['6','7','8']
```

The numbers i have got from a loop.I am a newbie to Python.

Comment: Use the `.index()` method

Comment: What does your existing code look like?

Comment: If you are a newbie and don't understand why the answers posted here works, the topic you are after is **list slicing** in python. Example [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
result = A[A.index('7')-1:A.index('7')+2]
```

But this only works with the first occurence of the searched item.

If you have more than one occurence of the item, use this:

```
A = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','7','11','12']

indexes = [ind for ind, val in enumerate(A) if val == '7']
for ind in indexes:
    result = A[ind-1:ind+2]
    print result
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be *slightly* more efficient *[complexity: `O(2N)` rather than `O(N)`]* to store the `index` first, then `slice`:

```
i = A.index("7")
desired_result = A[i-1:i+2]
#['6', '7', '8']
```

---

The reason this works is that `A.index(x)` will return the index of `x` in the `list` - `A`. So in your example, `A.index(7)` would return `6` (remember lists start at `0`). We then store this in a variable - `i` - to save calculating it again.

Then, we use list [`slicing`](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) to extract the section of the list one either side of the index. The syntax of `slicing` in general is:

```
[start : stop : step]
```

where all three options are optional and defaults of `0`, `len(list)` and `1` will be used if emitted.

But you need to remember that, like with the `range()` function, this only slices **up to** stop, so we need to use a slice from `i-1` to `i+2` (which will include `i+1` but *not* `i+2`).

---

The only *slight* problem with `slicing` this simply is if we are searching for an `element` which is the very first element in `A` - so here that would be `"1"`. It wouldn't work in this case as `A.index("1")-1` would be `-1` (as `0 - 1 = -1`) and all `slicing` treats negative values as indexes from the end of the list. This would mean are `slice` in this unique case would be `A[-1: 1]` which would result in an empty list (`[]`) for obvious reasons.

So, to fix this, all we need to do is make sure that the start index is *never* negative - if it is, we want it to be `0`.

To achieve this, we could use a `ternary` which would look like:

```
desired_result = A[i-1 if i-1 < 0 else 0:i+2]
```

or, more succinctly, we could use `max()`:

```
desired_result = A[max(0,i-1):i+2]
```

which would both now produce the correct `slices` for all inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line solution that gets all matches of the searched character, returns the adjacent ones, and even wraps around if the matched character is at the beginning of the set

```
A = ['7','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','7','11','12']

output = [[A[idx-1], c, A[idx+1]] for idx, c in enumerate(A) if c=='7' and idx+1<len(A)]


print(output) # [['12', '7', '1'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['10', '7', '11']]
```

if you want something that returns only one index if the '7' is at the beginning or end it'll have to be a multiline function like this:

```
A = ['7','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','7','11','12', '7']
output = []

for idx, c in enumerate(A):
  if c=='7':
    output_list = []
    if idx == 0: # beginning of list
      output_list=[c, A[idx+1]] if idx+1<len(A) else None
    elif idx == len(A)-1: # end of list
      output_list=[A[idx-1], c] if idx-1>0 else None
    else: #somewhere in the middle
      output_list = [A[idx-1],c,A[idx+1]]
    output.append(output_list)

print(output) # [['7', '1'], ['6', '7', '8'], ['10', '7', '11'], ['12', '7']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are more elegant ways to do it but...:

```
A = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
print(A.index('7'))  # index of the seeked item
ll = [
    A[A.index('7')-1+i] for i in range(0,3)
    ]
print(ll)  # ['6', '7', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using a for loop and enumerate, this also happens to handle the case for repeats of '7', and the start, and end of a list, and has the added benefit of only iterating the list 1 time, it also assumes the list is unsorted:

```
for index, item in enumerate(A):
    if item is '7':
        # is first
        if index == 0:
             print('start', item, A[index+1])
        # is last
        elif index == len(A)-1:
            print(A[index-1], item, 'end')
        else:
             print(A[index-1], item, A[index+1])
```